# Player join event and player login event not working (minecraft bukkit coding)

Tags: java, bukkit

Ok, so since i updated to java 8, nothing works properly in my code, only the console logging and some commands. One thing im using to text it and find the solution is just a basic player join message. As far as i can see, there is nothing wrong with this code:

```
package core.global.idv1.stats;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerLoginEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class CoreStats extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("[CoreStats] Has been enabled!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("[CoreStats] Has been disabled!");
    }

    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("sendme")){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "Sent");    
    }
        return false;

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
    Player p = e.getPlayer();
    p.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Welcome to the server");
    }
}
```

I have tried both PlayerJoinEvent and PlayerLoginEvent. 
Iv been trying to fix this thing for 3 days now so any help would be awesome.
 Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bukkit, but at least with Forge, you have to register the class with the event bus in order for Event Handlers to be "picked up".  Is there a similar requirement with Bukkit (if so, did you register it)?  This is what I mean in my main mod file with Forge `MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(new Handler());`

Comment: Im pretty new to java coding and bukkit coding so i dont really know what that means lol but i was using this a much larger chunk of code with a bunch of other event handlers an that was working fine about a week ago. But then i updated java to java re 8 or something and its stopped working

Comment: Also, this isnt a mod, its a Craftbukkit server plugin

Comment: Putting it simply, what I mean is this: the main mod file registers (well, you have to register them) other files that contain event handlers, so that when the event is fired, your custom code will get executed.  Without "registering" these other files through, the game doesn't "know" to use your code instead of the vanilla code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register your `Listener` first:

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {
    Bukkit.getServer().getPluginManager().registerListeners(this, this);
    getLogger().info("[CoreStats] Has been enabled!");
}
```

For more information, have a look at the [bukkit wiki](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Event_API_Reference).